# How to get Squid V4 to log "requestless" connections

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a Squid proxy (V4.13), and it isn't logging all connections that are going through it. According to [this message](https://www.spinics.net/lists/squid/msg95668.html), before V5 "older Squids did not access-log many requestless TCP connections"

I'm not interested in any details from inside the connections, just the IP and port number pairs being used.

In the example "squid.conf" there is a section under "acl" that shows defining a "hasRequest" ACL that then is used in two "access_log" definitions. But the "logformat=" values in there are custom ones, and there is no definition of what they are.

So is there a full example somewhere of how to log these "requestless" connections in Squid V4? I guess what I need that I don't have at the moment, is a "logformat" definition that is compatible with the information that is availale in such a connection.